# dynamically change the length of String inside the EditText field in Android

Tags: java, android, regex, android-edittext

I am using an EditText field in my application.

EditText  is for entering the ddns input:

```
  e.g    www.example.com/xxxx
```

I want to restrict the length of the ddns id to 30 characters after "/" character.

i.e after "/" character, what follows must be of maximum 30 characters

I want to do it dynamically and restrict user to not type more than 30 characters.

How can i  do it.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/sK8oK9/11

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below way to restrict the user to enter less than 30 character.

```
tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //processing part
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A very fast and ugly answer would look something like this:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(s.toString().contains('/') {
            if(s.toString().split('/')[1].length() == 30) {
                //By only working with the EditText:                   
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                                    getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                yourEditText.setFocusable(false);
                yoruEditText.setEnabled(false);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }});
```

```js
    //What i think is the best implementation, adding a TextView sitting on top of      
    //EditText with visibility set to GONE
 yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.toString().contains('/') {
                if(s.toString().split('/')[1].length() == 30) {
                    //By working with EditText and a TextView
                    yourEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    yourTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    yourTextView.setText(s);
                    
                     
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            
        }});
```

In any case you want to add a textWatcher to your editText and change it accordingly.

Comment: I tried your implementation above, i can set text. But what i see is that after 30 characters, the cursor goes to the start of the Edittext area and then starting printing from the beginining .for all subsequent characters i type after 30 char limit, it starts printing from the beginning. I want to stop user from typing after it reach 30 character. User should not be able to type again